# Experimental design study on arousal/attention

Tags: experiment-design, factor-analysis, predictor, dependent-variable

I hope this question is simple enough, suits this forum and does not consume much of your time. Essentially, want to make sure I have the appropriate design that answers my research question without interference from any confounding variables.

I want to specifically test the effect of an independent variable emotional arousal (high vs. low) on distraction measured by dependent variable (RTs).
For this I have an intersubject where in one condition two letters are superimposed against high arousal background images (condition 1) and in a different condition against low arousal background images (condition 2). The task is to judge whether the two letters are congruent (even) or incongruent (odd) and I want to control for this congruency/incongruency effect.

For this, across the two conditions I have used the same exact congruent and incongruent letters but the order in which they appear are randomized to avoid any sequential effect. To my view what really varies across varies is the emotional arousal while the congruency/incongruency factor is matched.
Is my design correct am I specifically testing the effect of variable emotional arousal (high vs. low) on distraction measured by dependent variable (RTs) and controlling for the confounding variable (congruency/incongruency)?

Thank you so much in advance

Jose

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to CV! Your question may be a bit more about subject knowledge than statistics, but probably enough about statistics to fit here :)

In my reading, you will be able to find out the effect of high vs. low intensity on reaction time with your study design, assuming you are controlling for relevant confounding variables.

What is confusing to me is that you say the task your participants do is to judge congruency/incongruency but you also say you want to control for the "congruency/incongruency effect"? But in general, if your 2 conditions are identical in all aspects except the high vs. low arousal evoking background, and reaction time is a good measure of distraction (probably is), the design should work as intended.